# Loading a PHP Page on Cordova App

Tags: javascript, php, cordova

I'm currently experimenting with cordova, trying to develop an app. I am running it on a windows server which has multiple websites that uses PHP pages.

I currently have a HTML version of this code but I thought I would copy the code and save it into a .php file and add php code to test it out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' http://xxxx 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css">
        <title>App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="welcomepage_banner" class="welcomepage_banner">
            <?php echo "hello"; ?>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angularjs_1_2_10.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-ui-bootstrap_0_11_0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So I run node.js and to test it out, I run the app on the browser which appears as: `http://localhost:8000/login.php`

But all this does is downloads the page. Other websites on the server that runs as PHP files/pages seem to work but this does not. Is this possible at all?

Comment: you can't use <?php echo "hello"; ?> you need to post to your server and return data with json ..

Comment: "Other websites on the server" — When you say "the server" do you mean `http://localhost:8000` or some other HTTP server running on port 80 of the same physical computer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something Like this :

```
<div id="welcomepage_banner" class="welcomepage_banner">
   <span id="yourid">  </span>
</div>


  $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "http://Your-serveur.com/index.php",
                 data: {"data":"Your data"},
                 async: true,
                 success: function(data)
                 { 
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                   $("#yourid").html(obj.data.var);
                }

        });
```